# Does I2P have a test network?

Tags: kovri, i2p, testnet

Does I2P have a test network ?

If not, how are the major changes tested ?

Comment: all the testing is done live right now, some people are trying to get a testing router made to make testing easier on the live network

Comment: If this question is about Kovri specifically (and not I2P in general) can you edit your question to make that clear?

Comment: It's about both

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no current public I2P testnet.

The I2P protocol already specifies a NETWORK_ID (equal to 2 for mainnet), so it should be easy to add.